# In PL/SQL, can I pass the table schema of a cursor FROM clause via a stored procedure parameter?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In PL/SQL, I would like to pass in a "source" schema as a parameter to a stored procedure.  For instance:

```
BEGIN
    CURSOR my_cursor IS
      SELECT my_field FROM <schema>.my_table
...
```

I want the 'schema' value to come from an input parameter into the stored procedure.  Does anyone know how I could do that?

P.S. Sorry if this is a stupid simple question, but I'm new to PL/SQL and must get some functions written quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to what Mark Brady said, another dynamic SQL option is to use a REF CURSOR.  Since your sample code includes a cursor this would be the most relevant.

```
PROCEDURE select_from_schema( the_schema VARCHAR2)
IS
  TYPE my_cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
  my_cursor  my_cursor_type;
BEGIN
  OPEN my_cursor FOR 'SELECT my_field FROM '||the_schema||'.my_table';

  -- Do your FETCHes just as with a normal cursor

  CLOSE my_cursor;
END;
```

Comment: That's exactly what a ref cursor is for .. some disadvantages (type checking?), but works for what you have in mind.

Comment: If you are on 9i or later, you can eliminate the TYPE declaration and just declare my_cursor to be of type SYS_REFCURSOR

Comment: Beware of SQL injection if you take this approach

Comment: You have to be aware of SQL injection with any dynamic SQL approach.  But in this case I am guessing the schema name is not coming directly from user input.

Comment: No, here the schema is coming from a configuration file on the server itself.  It is only a backdoor for developers to switch the schema in which a data feed is flowing.

Answer (score 3):

This has to be done with dynamic sql.

Either the DBMS_SQL package or the Execute Immediate statement.

You can't use variables in the FROM clause.

A potential solution may be to

ALTER SESSION SET Current_Schema = '' <-- the schema you want.

That command changes the default schema. SO if you have a bunch of identically named tables you can save yourself dynamic SQL and make a Dynamic Alter Session.