# PL/SQL get schema name from table

Tags: plsql

Sorry im new to Oracle store procedure, I have a cursor declared to query table from another schema as following:

```
CURSOR A IS select * from <schema>.Employee where conditions
```

My schema's name is actually being kept in a table, say, Table A, so I need to query from Table A and pass it in the cursor as variable.

Does anyone know how I could do that?

Comment: you need to use dynamic SQL.  Google "execute immediate" and ref cursors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PL/SQL, can I pass the table schema of a cursor FROM clause via a stored procedure parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278882/in-pl-sql-can-i-pass-the-table-schema-of-a-cursor-from-clause-via-a-stored-proc)